# PDF downloads stopped in Firefox

Tags: firefox, pdf

I was hoping for a way to fix my PDF downloads from being "stopped" when being automatically opened from my website.

Comment: you should be a little more specific...

Comment: When you click on the open pdf button on my website, the pdf does not open in firefox. The button of the browser window reads stopped.

Comment: Are you expecting an in-browser view of the pdf with software like Acrobat reader?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The PDF is getting stopped because your script on the web server is either

1. not serving the correct mime type (response content type)
2. not buffering (response buffer)
3. poorly written - spaces between script tags which are illegal for the mime type
4. getting killed prematurely by the server software